# Reuse UITableViewCells to show a state like favourite?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with a large amount of custom cell. Each cell has a utilityButton so when you swipe the cell from right to left, you can select `Favourite` or `Delete`.

Also, when selected Favourite, the Favourite button inside the utilityButton will become *RED*, otherwise button is *WHITE*.

The issue is after I scrolled the tableView, the cell's favourite buttons that I had selected (They were ever *RED*) became *WHITE*. I guess I missed something important in my cell reuse method.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ColorCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    [cell setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    [cell setRightUtilityButtons:[self rightButtons] WithButtonWidth:58.0f];
    cell.delegate = self;
    return cell;
}

- (NSArray *)rightButtons
{
    NSMutableArray *rightUtilityButtons = [NSMutableArray new];
    [rightUtilityButtons sw_addUtilityButtonWithColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.78f green:0.78f blue:0.8f alpha:1.0] icon:[UIImage imageNamed:@"heart"]];
    [rightUtilityButtons sw_addUtilityButtonWithColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:0.231f blue:0.188 alpha:1.0f] icon:[UIImage imageNamed:@"trash"]];
    return rightUtilityButtons;
}
```

This is the cell's delegate method will be called when trigger the utilityButton and shows how I set the selected button's image, while `heart` is *WHITE* and `heart-selected` is *RED*. Note that `index == 0` is the favourite button and the delete button is following.

[image]

```
- (void)swipeableTableViewCell:(ColorCell *)cell didTriggerRightUtilityButtonWithIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    NSIndexPath *cellIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    ColorModel *model = [self.objects objectAtIndex:cellIndexPath.row / 2];
    if (cellIndexPath.row % 2 == 0) {
        switch (index) {
            case 0:
            {
                if ([self.favouriteArray containsObject:model]) {
                    [self.favouriteArray removeObject:model];
                    [cell.rightUtilityButtons.firstObject setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"heart"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                }else{
                    [self.favouriteArray addObject:model];
                    [cell.rightUtilityButtons.firstObject setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"heart-selected"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                }
                [cell hideUtilityButtonsAnimated:YES];
                break;
            }
            case 1:
            {
                [self.objects removeObjectAtIndex:cellIndexPath.row / 2];
                [self.tableView reloadData];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you scroll the table view its reloads its cells, and in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method you are resetting/ assigning new set of utility buttons and in that case heart button is white

```
[cell setRightUtilityButtons:[self rightButtons] WithButtonWidth:58.0f];
```

Instead of it you can write your `rightButtons` method like below and it will solve the problem. You also don't need to listen for `didTriggerRightUtilityButtonWithIndex`

```
- (NSArray *)rightButtonsForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexpath
{
    NSMutableArray *rightUtilityButtons = [NSMutableArray new];
    if (/* row is selected*/) {
        [rightUtilityButtons sw_addUtilityButtonWithColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.78f green:0.78f blue:0.8f alpha:1.0] icon:[UIImage imageNamed:@"heart-selected"]];
    } else {
        [rightUtilityButtons sw_addUtilityButtonWithColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.78f green:0.78f blue:0.8f alpha:1.0] icon:[UIImage imageNamed:@"heart"]];
    }

    [rightUtilityButtons sw_addUtilityButtonWithColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:0.231f blue:0.188 alpha:1.0f] icon:[UIImage imageNamed:@"trash"]];
    return rightUtilityButtons;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because of the cell reuse. You should set button's correct color based on whether it is favourited in your `- (NSArray *)rightButtons`.